# Identify triplets of capital letters

Tags: regex

I am looking to extract a series of 3 letter codes from a dataset.
Each entry has a set of 3 capitalized letters that aren't "CCV," but they
vary in their placement in each entry.

Currently I am trying:
    `(?!CCV)[A-Z]{3}`

I have a dataset of entries like:

`CCV_21123214_AAA
 CCV_02390394_AAC
 094804958_AAA_ee9r80
 BLAH_CCV_odfdkk_BBB`

and want:

`AAA
 AAC
 AAA
 BBB`

The problem is my current approach keeps grabbing letters from other capitalized words longer than 3 letters like "BLAH", getting parts of it as triplets like:

`AAA
 BLA
 LAH
 AAC`

Is there a way to find only triplets of capitalized letters?

Comment: Which language or tool are you using?

Comment: I'm working mostly in R.

Comment: Use a pair of negative lookarounds at both ends `(?<![A-Z])(?!CCV)[A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might want is something like this:

```
(?<=\b|_)(?!CCV)[A-Z]{3}(?=\b|_)
```

First, it'll look behind, to ensure that the previous token is either an underscore or word boundary (`\b`). Then, it'll look ahead to ensure it's not finding the dreaded `CCV`. Then it'll match the 3 capitals, and then look ahead to ensure that the next token is either an underscore or a word boundary.

[Demonstration at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aL9oU4/1)

Since you're working in R, you'll need to escape the backslashes, yielding

```
(?<=\\b|_)(?!CCV)[A-Z]{3}(?=\\b|_)
```

as your final pattern string.

Comment: It works for the most part, but for some reason, it is not detecting the codes if they are at the end of the entry. For example, tddAH_CCV40413269_AAC is not returning AAC.

Comment: It's working OK when I test it. Does R require you to escape the backslashes?

Comment: That is what was missing, Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you only are interrested in find ing rows with the letters, or can use capture groups to extract the combination, you could go with

```
(?:\b|_)(?!CCV)([A-Z]{3})(?:\b|_)
```

It checks for a word boundary (`\b`) or an underscore (`_`), not being followed by `CCV`, capturing (just matching if you remove the parentheses) the letters, and then again matching a word boundary or underscore.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yF1uN4/2).

If look-behinds are supported (not javascript) then you could go with

```
(?<=\b|_)(?!CCV)([A-Z]{3})(?=\b|_)
```

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/yF1uN4/4).